# Convert List to Pandas Dataframe Column

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I need to convert my list into a one-column pandas dataframe.

Current List (len=3):

```
['Thanks You',
 'Its fine no problem',
 'Are you sure']
```

Required Pandas DF (shape =3,):

```
0 Thank You
1 Its fine no problem
2 Are you sure
```

N.B. The numbers represent index in the required Pandas DF above.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73931762/19123103) may be useful, if you want to assign a list to an existing dataframe.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

Use:

```
L = ['Thanks You', 'Its fine no problem', 'Are you sure']

#create new df 
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':L})
print (df)

                   col
0           Thanks You
1  Its fine no problem
2         Are you sure
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'oldcol':[1,2,3]})

#add column to existing df 
df['col'] = L
print (df)
   oldcol                  col
0       1           Thanks You
1       2  Its fine no problem
2       3         Are you sure
```

Thank you [DYZ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049147/convert-list-to-pandas-dataframe/42049158#comment71270875_42049158):

```
#default column name 0
df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)
                     0
0           Thanks You
1  Its fine no problem
2         Are you sure
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(L)`

Answer (score 40):

If your list looks like [1,2,3], you can do:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [1,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame([lst])
df.columns =['col1','col2','col3']
df
```

To get this:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0    1        2        3
```

Alternatively, you can create a column as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([lst]).T)
df.columns =['col1']
df
```

To get this:

```
  col1
0    1
1    2
2    3
```

Answer (score 10):

You can directly call the [`pd.DataFrame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) method and pass your list as the parameter.

```py
import pandas as pd
l = ['Thanks You', 'Its fine no problem', 'Are you sure']
pd.DataFrame(l)
```

Output:

```
                      0
0             Thanks You
1    Its fine no problem
2           Are you sure
```

And if you have multiple lists and you want to make a dataframe out of it. You can do it as following:

```py
import pandas as pd

names = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
salary = [50000, 90000, 41000, 62000]
age = [24, 24, 23, 25]
data = pd.DataFrame([names, salary, age]) # Each list would be added as a row
data = data.transpose() # To Transpose and make each rows as columns
data.columns = ['Names', 'Salary', 'Age'] # Rename the columns
data.head()
```

Output:

```
    Names    Salary    Age
0        A    50000     24
1        B     90000     24
2        C     41000     23
3        D     62000     25
```

Answer (score 4):

Example:

```
['Thank You',
 'It\'s fine no problem',
 'Are you sure?']
```

Code block:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

Output:

```
    0
0    Thank You
1    It's fine no problem
2    Are you sure?
```

It is not recommended to remove the column names of the Pandas dataframe. But if you still want your data frame without header (as per the format you posted in the question) you can do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
df.columns = ['']
```

Output will be like this:

```
0    Thank You
1    It's fine no problem
2    Are you sure?
```

Or

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lst).to_string(header=False)
```

But the output will be a list instead of a dataframe:

```
0             Thank You
1  It's fine no problem
2         Are you sure?
```

Answer (score 3):

For converting a list into Pandas core data frame, we need to use **DataFrame** method from the **pandas** package.

There are different ways to perform the above operation (assuming Pandas is imported as `pd`)

1. `pandas.DataFrame({'Column_Name':Column_Data})`

- **Column_Name** : String
- **Column_Data** : List form

2. ```
    Data = pandas.DataFrame(Column_Data)`
    Data.columns = ['Column_Name']
   ```

So, for the above mentioned issue, the code snippet is

```
import pandas as pd

Content = ['Thanks You',
           'Its fine no problem',
           'Are you sure']

Data = pd.DataFrame({'Text': Content})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list = ['Thanks You', 'Its fine no problem', 'Are you sure']
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
```

Output:

```
                   0
0           Thanks You
1  Its fine no problem
2         Are you sure
```

Column name:

```
df.columns = ['col name']
```

Comment: please add more explanation for others to understand your answer better

Answer (score 1):

You can also `assign()` a list to an existing dataframe. This is especially useful if you're chaining multiple methods and you need to assign a column that you need to use later in the chain.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
df1 = df.assign(col=['Thanks You', 'Its fine no problem', 'Are you sure'])
```

[image: res]