# What will it give me and how to access the elements?

Tags: python, list

Please look at this piece of code :

```
sig_array=[]
...
for i in range (0, 2):
        ....
        temp=[]
        for k in range (0, len (sig)):
            #print (k)
            temp.append(downsample(sig[k],sampl, new_freq))
        sig_array.append(temp)
```

In other words, `temp`is a list of arrays (my `downsample`function, as its name may suggest, return an array) and then the `temp` will be agregated so it would be a list of lists of arrays !

My questions are : How to deal with that (indexing, ...) and is there simplest way to proceed, by generating list of arrays in a loop but how to keep it in a data structure ?

Thanks

Comment: What's the use of `i` here?

Comment: what do you need to use that for exactly? easy data access? Matrix processing? Maybe have a look at numpy ndarrays and such

Comment: @Bazingaa. Actually, I did not put all the code to focus on my issue but roughly, keep in mind that different values of `i` give different `sig` (not necessary of same length from one`i`to another. Hope it's clear

Comment: Have you tried considering list comprehension? It will make your code less verbose

Comment: What about using `extend` instead of `append` to remove the list of list problem? Something like `temp.extend(....)`

Comment: @smagnan Actually I want to do big data on time series. Actually, a single data (i.e. an element of `sig_array`) is represented by several time series (each one is a `temp` of several values)

Comment: @Bazingaa Could you provide detail ?

Comment: Adi219 already posted the solution I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding indexing, you'd just refer to elements like `sig_array[0]`, `sig_array[1][2]` or `sig_array[3][0][2]` etc.

Regarding any better data structures, it really just depends on your use case. As @smagnan says in the comments, are you using it for easily accessing data? Matrix processing? If so, have a look at `numpy ndarrays`. **You say that you need it for big data on time series analysis. In that case, using the `pandas` module will be quite helpful ([more info](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/time-series-analysis-tutorial)).**

Also, as @Bazingaa says, you can make your code less verbose by using `list` comprehensions ([more info](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)):

```
sig_array = [ [downsample(sig[i],sampl, new_freq) for i in range (len(sig))] for _ in range(2)]
```

With `list` comprehensions, it's best to start from the outside, and from the end. The `for _ in range(2)` will run twice (I've replaced your `i` with `_` as I couldn't see you using it anywhere. If you need it, replace `_` with a relevant variable name). In each iteration, it'll `append` the inner list comprehension to the `sig_array`. Inside the inner listcomp, the result of the `downsample()` function will be appended to the temporary `list` for each iteration of the `for` loop,

This will have exactly the same output as your code, but is clearly *way* shorter :)

Comment: I have explained my "reasons" in comments above, could you look at it ?

Comment: @Adi219: It would be helpful to the OP if you also explain to him *briefly* what's going on inside the list, especially the `_` which replaced `i`. I asked him about `i`. May be he needs some operation which depends on `i`. So better to explain. Also just replace `range (0, len (sig))` by `range(len (sig))`

Comment: @Bazingaa Thanks for your care. Also, taking into account my "needs" as mentioned below, would you have a data structure to advise me ?

Comment: @MysteryGuy I've edited it to cater for your 'needs'.

Comment: @Adi219 Saw your edit about `pandas` but in the tuto, they just read a well-done `csv` and that is ok. In my case, I am reading EEG files and need to build my data quite on my own

Comment: So, I would be interested if it was possible to transform a heavy structure like the one I proposed above in a pandas dataframe for example

Comment: @MysteryGuy It's possible :) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049147/convert-list-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @MysteryGuy Also if this answer's helpful, please can you accept (and possibly upvote ;) ) this answer? (as it'll help other users in the future who encounter your problem know which solution worked for you)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177731/discussion-between-mysteryguy-and-adi219).

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation.