# How to read nested json data values in python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, key-value, flatten

Im trying to read a nested json file into python . Its in the following format -

```
{

"13638": {

    "Advocate Name": "BRET ALLEN",

    "No. of Cases": "2",

    "WP 15699/2019": {

         "Case Category": "SERVICE",

         "District": "HYDERABAD",

         "Filing Date": "23/07/2019",

         "Registration Date": "24/07/2019",

         "Listing Date": "26/08/2019",

         "Case Status": "PENDING"
          },

    "CRLP 804/2019": {

         "Case Category": "-",
         "District": "HYDERABAD",
         "Filing Date": "12/02/2019",
         "Registration Date": "12/02/2019",
         "Listing Date": "21/06/2019",
         "Case Status": "PENDING"
         }

},

"231": 
   {

    "Advocate Name": "DAISY LEE",

    "No. of Cases": "28",

    "WP 1518/2019": {
         "Case Category": "NON-SERVICE",
         "District": "HYDERABAD",
         "Filing Date": "28/01/2019",
         "Registration Date": "28/01/2019",
         "Listing Date": "11/02/2019",
         "Case Status": "DISPOSEDClick here to see the Order"
          },
       "WP 2896/2019": {
         "Case Category": "NON-SERVICE",
         "District": "HYDERABAD",
         "Filing Date": "12/02/2019",
         "Registration Date": "13/02/2019",
         "Listing Date": "-",
         "Case Status": "PENDING"
         }
 }

}
```

I am considering 2 Keys in the above data - "13638" & "231" . I want to access the "Case Status" field and convert it to dataframe.

Expected output:

---

### |Case status|

PENDING

PENDING

DISPOSEDClick here to see the Order

PENDING

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by looping over the dictionary.

```
case_status_list = []
for key, value in data.items():
    for nested_key, nested_value in value.items():
        try:
            status = nested_value.get("Case Status", None)
            case_status_list.append(status)
        except AttributeError as e:
            pass
print(case_status_list)
```

outut:

```
['PENDING', 'PENDING', 'DISPOSEDClick here to see the Order', 'PENDING']
```

And to convert to dataframe, you can [refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42049158/2861108)

```
L = ['Thanks You', 'Its fine no problem', 'Are you sure']

#create new df 
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':L})
print (df)

                   col
0           Thanks You
1  Its fine no problem
2         Are you sure
```

Comment: How can I collect all the values it in a dataframe or text instead of printing it?

Comment: @NajmaNaaz You can append the value to a list instead of printing it. I have updated the answer