# Python transpose/convert inconsistent lists into DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've parsed an xml document and got values like so:

```
row_list = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
col_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col1', 'col4', 'col2', 'col3', 'col5', 'col6']
values_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

The entire set of columns consists of about 100 elements and as you can see, the structure is inconsistent. Could you please advise on how to transform these lists into a DataFrame assigning particular values to rows and columns that would look like:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert List to Pandas Dataframe Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049147/convert-list-to-pandas-dataframe-column)

Comment: That is not related to the question at all @ZarakiKenpachi

Comment: Don't forget the *pandas* tag for pandas related questions @jabba (added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
row_list = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
col_list = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col1', 'col4', 'col2', 'col3', 'col5', 'col6']
values_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

out = {}
for r, c, v in zip(row_list, col_list, values_list):
    out.setdefault(r, {})[c] = v

print(pd.DataFrame({'id': k, **v} for k, v in out.items()).set_index('id').fillna(0))
```

Prints:

```
    col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
id                                    
0    1.0   2.0   3.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
1    4.0   0.0   0.0   5.0   0.0   0.0
2    0.0   6.0   7.0   0.0   8.0   9.0
```