# How to store lists in a variable as a data frame in Python?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, loops, store

I am trying to store these lists in a variable that is created from a loop as a data frame.

```py
X_train = X[new_features]
X_test = X_test[new_features]
X_outliers = test_outlier[new_features]
l = new_features
```

when I print `l`, it looks like the following. It has 180 lists inside of the loop.

```
['mfcc_1' 'mfcc_2' 'mfcc_4' 'mfcc_6' 'mfcc_3' 'mfcc_5' 'delta_0' 'mfcc_8'
 'mfcc_9' 'mfcc_7']
['mfcc_1' 'mfcc_2' 'mfcc_3' 'mfcc_4' 'delta_0' 'mfcc_5' 'mfcc_6' 'mfcc_7'
 'mfcc_8' 'mfcc_9']
['mfcc_1' 'mfcc_2' 'mfcc_4' 'mfcc_3' 'mfcc_6' 'mfcc_5' 'delta_0' 'mfcc_8'
 'mfcc_7' 'mfcc_10']
['mfcc_1' 'mfcc_2' 'mfcc_4' 'mfcc_6' 'mfcc_3' 'mfcc_5' 'mfcc_8' 'mfcc_7'
 'mfcc_10' 'delta_0']
['mfcc_1' 'mfcc_2' 'mfcc_3' 'mfcc_4' 'mfcc_6' 'delta_0' 'mfcc_5' 'mfcc_8'
 'mfcc_7' 'mfcc_10']
['mfcc_1' 'mfcc_2' 'mfcc_3' 'mfcc_4' 'mfcc_6' 'delta_0' 'mfcc_5' 'mfcc_8'
 'mfcc_7' 'mfcc_10'] ...
```

I would like to store those lists into a data frame. How could that be done?

Comment: store to a dictionary instead of a list, inside the loop and convert the dictionary to dataframe . otherwise use `list.append`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert List to Pandas Dataframe Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049147/convert-list-to-pandas-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 0):

Use `df = pd.DataFrame({'col':l})`

Also the question is terribly unclear. Do add an example of what you are expecting the output to be so we can help you.

Refer [for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049147/convert-list-to-pandas-dataframe-column)