# How to list to individual columns in CSV file?

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I have a script that I have been working on where I pull info from a text file and output it to a CSV file with specific column headers.
I am having an issue with writing to the correct columns with the output.  Instead of having it "interface_list" writing all the port names under "Interface", it instead writes all of them across the row.  I am having the same issue for my other lists as well.

This is what the output looks like in the csv file:

Current Output

[image: Current Output]

But I would like it to look like this:

Desired Output

[image: Desired Output]

I am kind of new to python but have been learning through online searches.

Can anybody help me understand how to get my lists to go in their respective columns?

Here is my code:

```
import netmiko
import csv
import datetime
import os
import sys
import re
import time


interface_pattern = re.compile(r'interface (\S+)')
regex_description = re.compile(r'description (.*)')
regex_switchport = re.compile(r'switchport (.*)')

    
with open('int-ports.txt','r') as file:
    output = file.read()
    
    with open('HGR-Core2.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['Interface', 'Description', 'Switchport'])
        
        interface_iter = interface_pattern.finditer(output)
        interface_list = []
        for interface in interface_iter:
            interface_list.append(interface.group(1))   
        writer.writerow(interface_list)
        
        description_iter = regex_description.finditer(output)
        description_list = []
        for description in description_iter:
            description_list.append(description.group(1))
        writer.writerow(description_list)   
        
        switchport_iter = regex_switchport.finditer(output)
        switchport_list = []
        for switchport in switchport_iter:
            switchport_list.append(switchport.group(0))

    f.close()
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] the other folks can run and include sample input data in text format that cam be used for testing.

Comment: Furthermore, I would recommend going with a Pandas dataframe instead. It will allow you to then easily manipulate it if needed and then you can export it to a csv with the inbuilt function?

Comment: Here is some text from int-ports.txt file that I am reading:

interface GigabitEthernet7/10
 description test1
 switchport trunk native vlan 999
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet7/11
 description test2 - Storage
 switchport access vlan 610
 switchport mode access
 speed auto 1000
 flowcontrol receive on
!
interface GigabitEthernet7/12
 description not in use
 switchport access vlan 99
 switchport mode access
 speed auto 1000
!
interface GigabitEthernet7/13
 description .
 switchport access vlan 99
 switchport mode access
 speed auto 1000

Answer (score 0):

Append can get very bittersome in loops.
People don't realize how resource hungry things can get quickly.

1.A.) [All hings to 1 dataframe that later you can export as csv](https://blog.finxter.com/how-to-convert-a-list-of-lists-to-a-csv-file-in-python/)

```
salary = [['Alice', 'Data Scientist', 122000],
          ['Bob', 'Engineer', 77000],
          ['Ann', 'Manager', 119000]]
# Method 2
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(salary)
df.to_csv('file2.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

1.B.) 1 list to 1 specific column in dataframe [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42049158/10270590)

```
L = ['Thanks You', 'Its fine no problem', 'Are you sure']

#create new df 
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':L})
print (df)

                   col
0           Thanks You
1  Its fine no problem
2         Are you sure
```

2.) Export as csv [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```
df.to_csv('name.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: So if I were to go the Panda's route, where would I place the code for it in my existing code?  I got it to work when I have a variable set into a list like your example, but when I am reading a text document to make these 3 different lists (interface_list, description_list and switchport_list), I am not sure how to take those lists and pass it into pd.dataframe correctly, as my code just errors out.

Comment: Nevermind, with some playing around, I got it to work.
Thank you for your help in this!

Comment: I am glad you made it. I also recommend numpy that is much faster with high lvl functions so you can make matrix based transformations to accelerate processes.