# Trying to create Dataframe from lists of zip using Pandas. wanted data table result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I'm scraping website and come to the part where to put it in Dataframe.
I tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42049158/17470235) but no expected output.

Here's my whole code

```
#driver chrome def
website = 'https://www.bitkub.com/fee/cryptocurrency'
path = r"C:\\Users\\USER\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe"
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get(website)

#giving variable
coin_name = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tbody//tr//td[2]//span")))]
chain_name = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tbody//tr//td[3]//div")))]
withdrawal_fees = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tbody//tr//td[4]//div")))]
#print(coin_name)
#print(chain_name)
#print(withdrawal_fees)

#for loop make list
for coin, chains, wdf in zip(coin_name, chain_name, withdrawal_fees):
    print("Coin name: {} Chain: {} Fee: {}".format(coin, chains, wdf))
#driver.quit
```

The output would be like this without being column yet. So I want it separate column by  'Coin name', 'Chain' and 'Fee'

```
Coin name: Civic(CVC) Chain: ETH (ERC20) Fee: 97.00000000 (CVC)
Coin name: (CVC) Chain: BSV Fee: 0.0004 (BSV)
Coin name: Bitcoin SV(BSV) Chain: ETH (ERC20) Fee: 0.00625000 (ETH)
Coin name: (BSV) Chain: BKC (KAP20) Fee: 0.01 (KUB)
Coin name: Ethereum(ETH) Chain: ETH (ERC20) Fee: 0.22000000 (COMP)
.
.
.
```

This is the input of variable I've scraped

```
print(coin_name)
['Civic(CVC)', '(CVC)', 'Bitcoin SV(BSV)', '(BSV)', 'Ethereum(ETH)', '(ETH)', 'Bitkub Coin(KUB)', '(KUB)', 'Compound(COMP)', '(COMP)', 'Curve DAO Token(CRV)', '(CRV)', 'Axie Infinity(AXS)', '(AXS)', 'The Sandbox(SAND)', '(SAND)', 'XRP(XRP)', '(XRP)', 'ChainLink Token(LINK)', '(LINK)', 'KyberNetwork(KNC)', '(KNC)', 'Stellar(XLM)', '(XLM)', 'Six(SIX)', '(SIX)', 'Everex(EVX)', '(EVX)', 'Alpha Finance Lab(ALPHA)', '(ALPHA)', 'Balancer(BAL)', '(BAL)', 'Litecoin(LTC)', '(LTC)', 'IOSToken(IOST)', '(IOST)', 'Cortex Coin(CTXC)', '(CTXC)', 'NEAR(NEAR)', '(NEAR)', 'Aave(AAVE)', '(AAVE)', 'Raiden Network Token(RDN)', '(RDN)', 'JFIN Coin(JFIN)', '(JFIN)', 'Basic Attention Token(BAT)', '(BAT)', 'Zilliqa(ZIL)', '(ZIL)', 'Polkadot(DOT)', '(DOT)', 'SushiSwap(SUSHI)', '(SUSHI)', 'Bitcoin Cash(BCH)', '(BCH)', 'Cardano(ADA)', '(ADA)', 'BNB Coin(BNB)', '(BNB)', 'Power Ledger(POW)', '(POW)', 'Secret Network(SCRT)', '(SCRT)', 'yearn.finance(YFI)', '(YFI)', 'Bitcoin(BTC)', '(BTC)', 'OmiseGO(OMG)', '(OMG)', 'Tether(USDT)', '(USDT)', 'Dogecoin(DOGE)', '(DOGE)', 'USD Coin(USDC)', '(USDC)', 'Maker(MKR)', '(MKR)', 'Enjin Coin(ENJ)', '(ENJ)', 'Kusama(KSM)', '(KSM)', 'Donnie Finance(DON)', '(DON)', 'Wancoin(WAN)', '(WAN)', 'StatusNetwork(SNT)', '(SNT)', '0x(ZRX)', '(ZRX)', 'Arcblock(ABT)', '(ABT)', 'Decentraland(MANA)', '(MANA)', 'Dai Stablecoin(DAI)', '(DAI)', 'Band Protocol(BAND)', '(BAND)', 'Golem Network Token(GLM)', '(GLM)', 'Uniswap(UNI)', '(UNI)', 'FTX Token(FTT)', '(FTT)', 'Ocean Protocol(OCEAN)', '(OCEAN)', 'Synthetix(SNX)', '(SNX)', 'Boba Token(BOBA)', '(BOBA)', 'Gala(GALA)', '(GALA)', 'GateToken(GT)', '(GT)', 'Songbird(SGB)', '(SGB)', 'GuildFi(GF)', '(GF)', 'Immutable X(IMX)', '(IMX)', 'Ethereum Name Service(ENS)', '(ENS)', 'dYdX(DYDX)', '(DYDX)', 'Illuvium(ILV)', '(ILV)', 'Aavegotchi(GHST)', '(GHST)', 'Chiliz(CHZ)', '(CHZ)', 'The Graph(GRT)', '(GRT)', 'Gods Unchained(GODS)', '(GODS)', 'Convex Finance(CVX)', '(CVX)', 'LUKSO(LYXE)', '(LYXE)', 'Crypto.com Coin(CRO)', '(CRO)', 'Yield Guild Game(YGG)', '(YGG)', 'Smooth Love Potion(SLP)', '(SLP)', 'Coin98(C98)', '(C98)', 'ShuttleOne(SZO)', '(SZO)', 'Popcoin(POP)', '(POP)', 'Experimental Finance(EXFI)', '(EXFI)', 'Solana(SOL)', '(SOL)', 'Avalanche(AVAX)', '(AVAX)', 'Polygon(MATIC)', '(MATIC)', 'Fantom(FTM)', '(FTM)', 'Terra(LUNA)', '(LUNA)']

print(chain_name)
['ETH (ERC20)', 'BSV', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'BKC (KAP20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'XRP', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'XLM', 'XLM', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'LTC', 'IOST', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'NEAR', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ZIL', 'DOT', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'BCH', 'ADA', 'BNB (BEP2)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'SCRT', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'BTC', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'DOGE', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'KSM', 'IOST', 'WAN', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'BAND', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'SGB', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'ETH (ERC20)', 'BKC (KAP20)', 'SGB', 'SOL', 'AVAX_C (AVAX)', 'MATIC (Polygon)', 'FTM (Fantom)', 'LUNA (Terra)']

print(withdrawal_fees)
['97.00000000 (CVC)', '0.0004 (BSV)', '0.00625000 (ETH)', '0.01 (KUB)', '0.22000000 (COMP)', '9.32000000 (CRV)', '0.49000000 (AXS)', '6.95000000 (SAND)', '0.25 (XRP)', '1.75000000 (LINK)', '4 (KNC)', '0.02 (XLM)', '1 (SIX)', '114.00000000 (EVX)', '72.00000000 (ALPHA)', '2.14000000 (BAL)', '0.001 (LTC)', '1 (IOST)', '0.1 (CTXC)', '0.01 (NEAR)', '0.28000000 (AAVE)', '55.00000000 (RDN)', '5.75000000 (JFIN)', '34.00000000 (BAT)', '0.2 (ZIL)', '0.1 (DOT)', '6.80000000 (SUSHI)', '0.001 (BCH)', '1 (ADA)', '0.00100000 (BNB)', '54.00000000 (POW)', '0.1 (SCRT)', '0.00120000 (YFI)', '0.0005 (BTC)', '5.99000000 (OMG)', '35.00000000 (USDT)', '5 (DOGE)', '35.00000000 (USDC)', '0.01400000 (MKR)', '15.00000000 (ENJ)', '0.01 (KSM)', '0.00840000 (DON)', '0.1 (WAN)', '514.00000000 (SNT)', '45.00000000 (ZRX)', '35 (ABT)', '9.82000000 (MANA)', '15 (DAI)', '0.01 (BAND)', '79.00000000 (GLM)', '2.64000000 (UNI)', '0.68000000 (FTT)', '39 (OCEAN)', '7.05 (SNX)', '10.00000000 (BOBA)', '90.00000000 (GALA)', '9.5 (GT)', '1 (SGB)', '10 (GF)', '11.00000000 (IMX)', '1.54000000 (ENS)', '11.00000000 (DYDX)', '0.04400000 (ILV)', '13 (GHST)', '105 (CHZ)', '48 (GRT)', '12 (GODS)', '1.8 (CVX)', '1.5 (LYXE)', '31 (CRO)', '5.42 (YGG)', '519 (SLP)', '11 (C98)', '170 (SZO)', '40 (POP)', '0.1 (EXFI)', '0.01 (SOL)', '0.01 (AVAX)', '0.1 (MATIC)', '0.01 (FTM)', '0.02 (LUNA)']
```

Comment: If you share the input you are using (after the webscrapping) it'd be a lot easier to help you debug it :)

Comment: @GabrielPellegrino Thank you. thought it didn't have to, so I put it out to not make a post too long. haha my bad. I edited now.

Comment: Hi, you didn't updated it with your input, you updated it with the import section of your script. I'd like to see the result of WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tbody//tr//td[2]//span"))) this call for example.

Comment: @GabrielPellegrino Ok. I updated again. hope I do it correctly this time. thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some how coin_name is twice as long as your other lists. Once you fix that you can do this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'coin_name': coin_name[0:81], 'chain_name': chain_name, 'withdrawal_fees':withdrawal_fees})

          coin_name       chain_name    withdrawal_fees
0        Civic(CVC)      ETH (ERC20)  97.00000000 (CVC)
1             (CVC)              BSV       0.0004 (BSV)
2   Bitcoin SV(BSV)      ETH (ERC20)   0.00625000 (ETH)
3             (BSV)      BKC (KAP20)         0.01 (KUB)
4     Ethereum(ETH)      ETH (ERC20)  0.22000000 (COMP)
..              ...              ...                ...
76       Maker(MKR)              SOL         0.01 (SOL)
77            (MKR)    AVAX_C (AVAX)        0.01 (AVAX)
78  Enjin Coin(ENJ)  MATIC (Polygon)        0.1 (MATIC)
79            (ENJ)     FTM (Fantom)         0.01 (FTM)
80      Kusama(KSM)     LUNA (Terra)        0.02 (LUNA)

[81 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the Dataframe now. fyi coin_name are from span and it got 2 elements in it.