# Pandas - Concatenating Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a script with `if` statements that has 14 possible dataframes

```
['result_14', 'result_13', 'result_12', 'result_11', 'result_10', 'result_9', 'result_8', 'result_7', 'result_6', 'result_5', 'result_4', 'result_3', 'result_2', 'result_1']
```

Not all dataframes are created every time I run the script. It is dependent on a secondary input variable. I am now attempting to concatenate dataframes but run into issue with those that do not exist.

```
pd.concat(([result_14, result_13, result_12, result_11, result_10, result_9, result_8, result_7, result_6, result_5, result_4, result_3, result_2, result_1]), ignore_index=True)

NameError: name 'result_13' is not defined
```

I have tried finding all dfs that exist in my python memory and parsing the results but this creates a list rather than a list of dataframes

```
alldfs = [var for var in dir() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]
SelectDFs = [s for s in alldfs if "result" in s]
SelectDFs

['result_14', 'result_15', 'result_12', 'result_11', 'result_10', 'result_9', 'result_8', 'result_7', 'result_6', 'result_5', 'result_4', 'result_3', 'result_2', 'result_1']

pd.concat(([SelectDFs]), ignore_index=True)
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
%who_ls  DataFrame
# %whos DataFrame
```

In your case

```
l = %who_ls  DataFrame
pd.concat([eval(dfn) for dfn in l if dfn.startswith('result')], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I have other dataframes loaded in memory that I would like to ignore. is there a way to only choose those that have the 'result' prefix?

Comment: @JSimon check the update

Comment: thanks for your help. though it is now being read as a string - throwing an error for concatenating:

Comment: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Comment: @JSimon check again .

Comment: That did it! thank you. so by adding eval(), you are preventing the list of dfs from being converted to a str?

Comment: @JSimon that is use df name which is str , to convert to the df ~

Answer (score 0):

You are passing list of string and not Dataframe object.

And once you re able to get DF Object you can pass `SelecteDFs` without bracket.

```py
pd.concat(SelectDFs, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to convert them into DFs? I mean when you want to concat them, it raise an error which says your data need to be dfs rahter than lists, so have you tried to convert your lists into DFs?

this link may help you:
[Convert List to Pandas Dataframe Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049147/convert-list-to-pandas-dataframe-column)

Comment: they are already dataframes which is how I am detecting the names in my loaded memory. the issue is that the code above reads them as a list